# Создание и заполнение массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Необходимо создать массив с элементами
[image: Массив который не обходимо создать]

n, k - данные который вводит пользователь

функция f(k)

[image: Функция f(k)]

Я совсем не понимаю задание
Мне необходимо создать двухмерный массив и в него запихать матрицу Zk,n
А вот чем его заполнить?
Совсем не понимаю задание, кому не сложно объясните.

Comment: Давайте разбираться по частям, что в этой задаче кажется самым непонятым?

Comment: приведу аналогию: таблица умножения. По строчкам пусть будет индекс n, по столбцам k. В таблице умножения пересечение на n и k - это число n*k, а у Вас - результат вычисления по формуле вашей

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял в чем проблема, если честно.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("n=");
    int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

    Console.Write("k=");
    int K = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

    var array = new double[N, K];
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            array[n, k] = n*F(k) + Math.Sin(k);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Result:");
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,8:F3}", array[n, k]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static double F(double x)
{
    return Math.Abs(Math.Cos(x*x) - 0.51)*Math.Sin(3*x - 4) - 4.44;
}
```